# Need help to find error in PHP and Curl code

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

I am trying to send SMS using fullonsms.com SMS gateway using curl and PHP.

Here is the code :-

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Error connecting to database');
    mysql_select_db('SMSapp') or die('Database Selection Error');
    $query='Select * from contacts';
    $cookie_file_path = "/cookie.txt"; 
    $username="*****";
    $password="***";
    $message=urlencode("Hi buddy");  

    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://sms.fullonsms.com/login.php");    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "MobileNoLogin=$username&LoginPassword=$password&x=16&y=14");

    $html=curl_exec($ch);        

    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
        $row_count=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($row_count==0)
        {
            echo 'Zero rows received';
            die();
        }  
        else 
        {
            for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://sms.fullonsms.com/home.php");    
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

                $tomobno=mysql_result($query_run,$i,'mobno');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ActionScript=%2Fhome.php&CancelScript=%2Fhome.php&HtmlTemplate=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fhtml%2Ffullonsms%2FStaticSpamWarning.html&MessageLength=140&MobileNos=$tomobno&Message=$message&Gender=0&FriendName=Your+Friend+Name&ETemplatesId=&TabValue=contacts");
                curl_exec($ch);
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }        
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $html;
?>
```

The script was working fine for 1 SMS but when i added the for lop and database thing to set `$tomobno`(mobile number) dynamically ,it stopped sending message.
The problem is that :-

I have three mobile numbers in my database.But I am not getting any SMS.

(I have echoed the numbers,the script is picking all of them.The problem is with CURL code.)I am a tyro in CURL.Please Help.

(Please do not unnecessarily downvote the question)

Comment: here is the wrking api for reference, if it can help you: https://github.com/kingster/FullonSMS-API/blob/master/fullonsms-api.php..

Comment: @Coderanonymous:Thanks for responding.But the problem is sending multiple SMS.The above script was working fine for 1 sms ,but when i modify it for multiple sms,it does not send any SMS.

Comment: I dont know what modifications you have done to get this working, all i suggest is revert the code, proceed step by step, and check at which step it failed. else mention or highlight the lines being changed by you.

Comment: @Coderanonymous : I just added the for loop and database thing to set `$tomobno`  dynamically.Rest is same.

Comment: not sure but maybe you should `curl_init()` and `curl_exec()` in loop as well.

Comment: @user1402647 : I tried that as well but no benefit.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Are you an Indian?

Comment: @VarunAgw:Why you think so?

Comment: FullonSMS is Indian SMS site

Comment: A free advise: CAPTCHA are increasingly popular among SMS sites.

Comment: @VarunAgw:I was developing application which covers many countries.Most countries' providers provide email-to-text facility but Indian providers don't.That's why I chose `fullonsms` due to its lower traffic.

Comment: Sounds cool, but beware of captcha. Also, are you going to ask user to register on fullonsms to send SMS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33754/discussion-between-insane-coder-and-varunagw)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, change code so you can a) read it easily and b) echo out what you have created, c) urlencode the whole string after you have built it.
This should help you spot the typo.

At a guess the phone number stored on the database has a space character in it, either as a prefic or suffix.

```
$tomobno=mysql_result($query_run,$i,'mobno');

$param = "ActionScript=\home.php&CancelScript=\home.php";
$param .= "&HtmlTemplate=\var\www\html\fullonsms\StaticSpamWarning.html&MessageLength=140";
$param .= "&MobileNos=$tomobno&Message=$message&Gender=0&FriendName=Your+Friend+Name&ETemplatesId=&TabValue=contacts";

echo $param;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode( $param) );
```